# I get an error when trying to create a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to create a new **React** app with:

`npx start-react-app my_new_app`

But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: crate-react-app@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hugovillalobos/.npm/_logs/2018-12-17T21_01_13_727Z-debug.log
Install for crate-react-app@latest failed with code 1
```

I attempted to do it with sudo privileges, but I just got the same error.

**EDIT**

I found that the error rises because I created the **React** app and then removed the whole directory in order to start over. Now, when I try to use the same directory name in the same parent directory, I get this error. When I use another directory, everything works with no problem.

I guess there should be some global **React** configurations that must be cleared besides just erasing the directory.

Comment: `npx create-react-app` not start

Comment: Sorry, it just a typo, I am using `npx create-react-app`

Comment: Did you look at the log file?

Comment: Looks like you ran 'crate-react-app' by accident. Could you update your question with the error you get when you fix that typo?

Comment: ^ Seems to be a simple typo...

Comment: Have you installed it? `npm install create-react-app`

Comment: @JossClassey You no longer need to install it globally if you're using npx...

Comment: I am sorry, @ack_inc is right, it is just a typo (I don't know how I managed to type it wrongly several times).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to follow steps here https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/ It should work.

```
npm i react react-dom --save-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow. Please copy the pertinent parts of that page here. Links can become out of date so that the information will be lost for future visitors.